# Nested DIVs - 4 divs (squares) of which 1 has 4 divs (squares) of which 1 has 4 divs (squares)

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

This is about nesting 4 divs (squares) in 1 div which is part of 4 divs ...

I'm using `display: flex` in the wrapper and for the wrapped items themselves, otherwise it wouldn't work

To me it feels like a bad hack but I try not to use float. How would you approach this topic?

Here's the demo on [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/favopub/edit?output).

And here is the HTML code:

```
<body>
<div>
  <div id="DIV">
    <div id="div1_inside_div" style="border:none">
      <div id="div2_inside_div1" style="border: none;">
        <div id="div3_inside_div2" style="border: none;">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div> 
          </div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>   
        </div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>   
    </div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>   
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
body {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto
}

/* DIV */

#DIV {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


#DIV > div{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 220px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: dashed 1px gray;
}

/* DIV1 INSIDE DIV */

#div1_inside_div {
   flex-wrap: wrap 
}

#div1_inside_div div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 50%;  
    background-color: yellow;
    border: dashed 1px black;
}

/* DIV2 INSIDE DIV1 */

#div2_inside_div1 {
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
}

#div2_inside_div1 div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 50%;  
    background-color: pink;
    border: dashed 1px black;
}


/* DIV3 INSIDE DIV2 */

#div3_inside_div2 {
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
}

#div3_inside_div2 div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 50%;  
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: dashed 1px blue;
}
```

Thank you!
J

Comment: Looks pretty good. Nice job. So what's the problem?

Comment: Thanks Michael_B. To me it seems like a hack; and since I have only been doing HTML and CSS for a few evenings over the past 2 weeks I'm not sure if that solution is appropriate. ..But according to your feedback, it seems to be okay. Good to know. Best, J.

Comment: It looks good. But now that you've completed the question we can review the code.

Comment: The code should be visible in JSbin too.

Comment: Right, but under SO guidelines, the code should be posted in the question, as well. What happens if one day your jsbin link goes dead? This question then becomes worthless as a reference source.

Answer (score 0):

you could for this problem take a look at using a framework such as Bootstrap, it will allow for you to solve this problem really easily with it's grid based element positioning system. In addition to this, Bootstrap will allow for your divs to be responsive automatically.

Worth a look, hope this helps:)

Comment: Hi Will! Yep, the the frameworks. I'm an absolute web development beginner and want to understand the gist of CSS (HTML and JavaScript) before I start taking the "short-cut route". I will be checking out Bootstrap soon. Cheers for the hint!

Comment: Hey! That's fair enough! Once you get an understanding of those things first, things like Bootstrap are definitely worth a look, although still coding, Bootstrap really can enhance your pages with responsiveness and cross browser compatibility as well. Good luck with it all:)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a hack.

Your elements are acting at the same time as flex containers, and as flex items from the upper level flex copntainer.

But, your code could be more DRY. For instance: reuse container and container-child thru all your layout:

```css
body {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

/* specific properties */
.level1 {
  height: 440px;
}

.level1 > div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: dashed 1px black;
}
.level2 > div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: dashed 1px black;
}
.level3 > div {
  background-color: pink;
  border: dashed 1px black;
}
.level4 > div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: dashed 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container level1">
    <div class="container level2">
      <div class="container level3">
        <div class="container level4">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
        </div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
      </div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for evaluating this, vals! Agreed, the code could be streamlined. Unfortunately, I still don't have enough points to upvote your post here. But I will do so once I have reached the magical threshold of "15". Best, J